# Mime type error in a resource

Tags: html, mime-types

I am working with a provider, he can't change his code, and he gave me next html code:

```
<img src="/Jobsite/GetFile.php?FileId=5611" class="lc-lcLogo">
```

> The problem is in all the browsers: Resource interpreted as Image but
>   transferred with MIME type text/html:
>   "http://abcdfd.com/Jobsite/GetFile.php?FileId=5611".

anyone has any idea how to fix it without my provider to do any changes?

Comment: Is this actually causing problems, other than console warning messages in Chrome?

Comment: yes, is a problem with all browsers. But only chrome show me the error

Comment: Response is sent by the server, where in header, it inserts resource mime type. So this needs fixing on the server side. You can't do anything on client side.

Comment: you have reason, I talk with my provider and I told about the change. We added this line: `HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", contentType);`
And the problem is fixed. Thanks!